# React native not showing Image from laravel API server

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5, react-native

I have a laravel server running in my laptop which servers some api data and image from the server. Note that, all api url's are protected with `auth:api` middleware, so each request should carry a bearer token.

When I try to access the image api url via postman tool, I am getting a proper image response.

[image]

But when I try to access the same image from the mobile app, it is not showing anything.

```
<Image
  source={{
    uri: 'http://192.168.43.245:8090/api/employers/logo/91w100.png',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Authorization : `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      Accept:"image/png",
      "Content-Type":"image/png"
    },

  }}
  style={{width: 20, height: 20}}
/>
```

And this is how I return response from laravel server.

```
public function getCheckedLogo($width)
{
    $width = ($width > 500) ? 500 : $width;
    $imagePath = $this->isCheckedLogoAvailable ? $this->getCheckedLogoPath() : resource_path('assets/img/no_logo_new.png');

    $img = Image::cache(function($image) use($width,$imagePath){
        $pxwidth = round(2.5 * 0.393701 * $width);
        $image->make($imagePath)->resize($pxwidth, null, function($constraint){
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        });
    },120,true);

    return $img->response()->setEtag($img->cachekey);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Does the problem only occur on iOS/Android or on both platforms?

Comment: if it occurs only on iOS it could be a problem with using HTTP instead of HTTPS

Comment: Why don't you just try `<Image source={{ uri: url_here }} style={{ height: 20, width: 20 }} />`